# How to do remove some httpresponse headers on each response like Server and ETag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[Using IIS 8 we can remove the ETag header by conf](http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2012/03/30/iis-8-0-to-use-or-not-to-use-etag-that-is-the-question.aspx) but how to do it if we use kestrel or an other server implementation ?

with ASP.Net, 4 I used the PreSendRequestHeaders event of global.asax :

```
    protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("ETag");
        }
    }
```

#### [Update]

I tried to use OnSendHeaders of IHttpResponseFeature but that doesn't work in all case, especialy with static files middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is a middleware to override the httpcontext

```
public class RemoveResponseHeadersMiddleware
{
    readonly IEnumerable<string> _headersToRemove;
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an instance of <see cref="RemoveResponseHeadersMiddleware"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next">the next <see cref="RequestDelegate"/> to call in the pipeline</param>
    /// <param name="optionsAccessor">the accessor to <see cref="CommaSeparatedListOptions"/> where headers to remove are configured</param>
    /// <param name="loggerFactory">the logger factory to create logger</param>
    public RemoveResponseHeadersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<CommaSeparatedListOptions> optionsAccessor, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (next == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("next");
        if (optionsAccessor == null || optionsAccessor.Options == null || optionsAccessor.Options.List == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("optionsAccessor");
        if (loggerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loggerFactory");

        _next = next;
        _headersToRemove = optionsAccessor.Options.List;
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next.Invoke(new RemoveHeaderHttpContext(context, _headersToRemove, _loggerFactory));            
    }
}
```

in the invoke method I create an httpcontext decorator with override the httpresponse

```
public class RemoveHeaderHttpContext : HttpContext
{
    readonly HttpContext _parent;
    readonly HttpResponse _response;
    /// <summary>
    /// Create instance of <see cref="RemoveHeaderHttpContext"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">the <see cref="HttpContext"/> to decorate/></param>
    /// <param name="headersToRemove">a list of unwanted header</param>
    /// <param name="loggerFactory">the logger factory to create logger</param>
    public RemoveHeaderHttpContext(HttpContext parent, IEnumerable<string> headersToRemove, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parent");
        if (headersToRemove == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("headersToRemove");
        if (loggerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loggerFactory");

        _parent = parent;
        _response = new RemoveHeaderHttpResponse(this, parent.Response, headersToRemove, loggerFactory);
    }

    public override HttpResponse Response
    {
        get
        {
            return _response;
        }
    }
```

this httpresponse is a decorator of httpresponse witch override the headers collection

```
public class RemoveHeaderHttpResponse : HttpResponse
{
    readonly HttpResponse _parent;
    readonly HttpContext _context;
    readonly IHeaderDictionary _headers;
    /// <summary>
    /// Create instance of <see cref="RemoveHeaderHttpResponse"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">the <see cref="HttpContext"/> associated to the HTTP respone</param>
    /// <param name="parent">the <see cref="HttpResponse"/> to decorate</param>
    /// <param name="headersToRemove">a list of unwanted header</param>
    /// <param name="loggerFactory">the logger factory to create logger</param>
    public RemoveHeaderHttpResponse(HttpContext context, HttpResponse parent, IEnumerable<string> headersToRemove, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parent");
        if (headersToRemove == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("headersToRemove");
        if (loggerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loggerFactory");

        _parent = parent;
        _context = context;
        _headers = new RemoveHeaderHeaderDictionary(parent.Headers, headersToRemove, loggerFactory);
    }

    public override IHeaderDictionary Headers
    {
        get
        {
            return _headers;
        }
    }
```

and this header dictionary filter headers added by other middleware in the pipeline

```
public class RemoveHeaderHeaderDictionary : IHeaderDictionary
{
    readonly IHeaderDictionary _parent;
    readonly IEnumerable<string> _headersToRemove;
    /// <summary>
    /// Logger
    /// </summary>
    public ILogger Logger { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an instance of <see cref="RemoveHeaderHeaderDictionary"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">the <see cref="IHeaderDictionary"/> to decorate</param>
    /// <param name="headersToRemove">a list of unwanted header</param>
    /// <param name="loggerFactory">the logger factory to create logger</param>
    public RemoveHeaderHeaderDictionary(IHeaderDictionary parent, IEnumerable<string> headersToRemove, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parent");
        if (headersToRemove == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("headersToRemove");
        if (loggerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loggerFactory");

        Logger = loggerFactory.Create<RemoveHeaderHeaderDictionary>();
        _parent = parent;
        _headersToRemove = headersToRemove;
        foreach (var header in headersToRemove)
            parent.Remove(header);
    }

    bool IsAllowedHeader(string header)
    {
        var allowed = !_headersToRemove.Any(h => h == header);
        Logger.WriteInformation(string.Format("{0} is {1}", header, allowed ? "allowed" : "not allowed"));
        return allowed;
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return _parent[key];
        }

        set
        {
            if (IsAllowedHeader(key))
                _parent[key] = value;
        }
    }
```

but maybe there's a mutch more simple way ?

[You can find the whole code on github, project ChatLe.HttpUtility](https://github.com/aguacongas/chatle/tree/master/src/ChatLe.HttpUtility)

Comment: OR, you can just use the response.OnSendingHeaders

Comment: Static files goes through an optimized code path which short circuits this code path.

Comment: No, test it. It works but it have to be the 1st middleware in the pipe