# Change the headers of static files in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using package `Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles` and configuring it in `Startup.cs` as `app.UseStaticFiles()`. How can I change the headers of the delivered files ? I want to set cache expiry etc for images, css and js.

Comment: [Caching static resources forever with ASP.NET Core](https://www.softfluent.com/blog/dev/2017/01/08/Caching-static-resources-forever-with-ASP-NET-Core)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use StaticFileOptions, which contains an event handler that is called on each request of a static file.

Your Startup.cs should look something like this:

```
// Add static files to the request pipeline.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
    {
        // Disable caching of all static files.
        context.Context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store";
        context.Context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
        context.Context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "-1";
    }
});
```

You can, of course, modify the above code to check the content type and only modify headers for JS or CSS or whatever you want.

Comment: Since these are static files as .css/.js, usually you should use an appropriate time for cache instead of `"no-cache, no-store"` to increase performance, eg: `context.Context.Response.Headers [HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "public, max-age=86400";` (86400 here is 24 hour = 24*60*60 sec). And to force bypass the cache when we update the files, We can also use `asp-append-version="true"` tag helper beside the `<link>`, `<script>` ... tags to add some auto generated query string based on hash of the files which will be auto-updated.

Answer (score 8):

Based on Josh Mouch's answer above, added code to determine if it's a pdf file

Startup.cs:

```
      app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
      {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
          {
            if(ctx.File.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf"))
            {
              ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "public,max-age=86400");
            }
            else
            {
              ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "public,max-age=31104000");
            }
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a solution allowing you to configure different behaviours for each environment (development, production & more), which is also the point of having these settings in the **web.config** file instead of hard-coding the whole stuff, you could consider the following approach.

Add the following key/value section in the **appsettings.json** file:

```
  "StaticFiles": {
    "Headers": {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store",
      "Pragma": "no-cache",
      "Expires": "-1"
    }
  }
```

Then add the following in the **Startup.cs** file's `Configure` method accordingly:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
    {
        // Disable caching for all static files.
        context.Context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = Configuration["StaticFiles:Headers:Cache-Control"];
        context.Context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = Configuration["StaticFiles:Headers:Pragma"];
        context.Context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = Configuration["StaticFiles:Headers:Expires"];
    }
});
```

This will allow the developer to define different cache settings using different/multiple/cascading settings files (`appsettings.json`, `appsettings.production.json` and so on) - which is something that could be done with the old `web.config` configuration pattern - with the ASP.NET Core's new one.

For additional info regarding the topic I also suggest to read [this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-static-files-cache-control-using-http-headers/) on my blog and/or these great articles from the official ASP.NET Core docs:

- [Configuration](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html)
- [Working with Static Files](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a middleware to do this, I've a sample that remove headers on my github https://github.com/aguacongas/chatle
Look at the ChatLe.HttpUtility project, it's a bit tricky. you can take a look of this question as well:

> [How to do remove some httpresponse headers on each response like Server and ETag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637845/how-to-do-remove-some-httpresponse-headers-on-each-response-like-server-and-etag)

However this will not work under `IIS`, because `IIS` manage statics files itself. It will work only on stand-alone application like `kestrel` or `firefly`

Comment: Do you mean all three of those won't work under IIS?  Or one of the answers, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Under IIS, you can add a web.config file to your wwwroot folder with header configurations.  An example that will control cache headers for all files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- Disable caching -->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That won't work if the websites host .NET Core modules (like in case of OP), as .NET Core doesn't honour `web.config`. The way .NET Core works is essentially running their own web server called Kestrel, which is hiding behind IIS + HTTP Module (aka ANCM, aka ASP.NET Core Module).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module