# Angular 2 beta 13 with Visual Studio 2015 update 2 / compile on save

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

After installing update 2 saving a TS file no longer compiles. I can force it with a "rebuild", simple build doesn't work.

I've tried changing Tools > Options > Text Editor > TypeScript > Project > General > Automatically compile TypeScript files which are not part of a project to checked and unchecked -- no difference.

Thoughts?

Comment: What version of TypeScript is installed? Help > About scroll down to TypeScript. Do you have a tsconfig.json file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download and install the latest version of [TypeScript](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) for Visual Studio 2015.

If you have a [tsconfig.json](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig.json.html) file in your root directory already, add `"compileOnSave": true`. If you don't have one, create one. (compileOnSave only works with TypeScript 8.4 or above according to the [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig.json.html).)

Here's what mine looks like:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/lib",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing compileOnSave since I took the tsconfig.json file from Angular. For others that try this: You have to reload the solution (or VS) before the setting takes place. Just updating tsconfig.json doesn't work.

Comment: Something else is still going on with VS. Most of the time it works, but then it stops compiling and so the JS files don't get generated; really weird. When this happens I don't see any errors anywhere, but the TS files don't get compiled.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't experienced that. It's been working fine for me for months now.

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks @rgvassar

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET Core you need to keep in mind that (some) caching is "on" by default. This can cause weird effects during development where sometimes an updated file is reloaded in the browser and other times it's not. Here's how you can disable caching: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34725559/29821

Comment: This now works.  Thanks!  Installing TypeScript 1.8.6 and setting compileOnSave makes it work.  I can even uncheck the option to compile TypeScript files not inside this solution!  You would have thought Microsoft should have fixed this once and for all, after a more than a year of this issue constantly happening...