# Disable Angular Templates in ASP.NET Core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core view using AngularJs I have:

```
<div ng-include="'/views/profile.html'" ng-controller="ProfileController as c"></div>
```

When I change the HTML file and run the application its content does not change.

I checked it and the HTML file is cached ...

How can I avoid the caching of angular HTML templates in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the headers of static files in Asp.net Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256244/change-the-headers-of-static-files-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Disable cache in your browser. Some non-disclosured browsers (with a orange fox logo) uses some really aggressive caching and do not seem to care much what the server says tend to create havoc when developing anything client sided like javascript etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this solution, I have got originally from the replies at the link given by @Deblaton in the comment here.

But, I modified for the purpose of ours'...

Just for development environment I disabled cache for only the HTML templates in the Configure() method of ASP.Net Core Request pipeline,

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
                {
                    if (context.File.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".html"))
                    {
                        context.Context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store";
                        context.Context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
                        context.Context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "-1";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
```

And it just did the work!