# Adding headers to iis static files not working in asp.net CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I want to add extra headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to my webAPI in order to consume this data in another project. At the moment I'm having this error:

> Failed to load http://localhost:49932/api/Restaurantes: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

The 49932 port runs my API and 4200 port is my AngularJS client. I have already tried adding them as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256244/change-the-headers-of-static-files-in-asp-net-core) but didn't worked:

in appsettings.json:

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
"ConexaoRestaurante": "data source=DESKTOP-R1CQGV1\\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=SSPI;"
},
  "Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
"Debug": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
},
"Console": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
},
"StaticFiles": {
  "Headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

In the `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        // tried both the commented and uncommented part:
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
            {
                // Disable caching for all static files.
                context.Context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = Configuration["StaticFiles:Headers:Access-Control-Allow-Origin"];
                context.Context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = Configuration["StaticFiles:Headers:Access-Control-Allow-Headers"];
                context.Context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = Configuration["StaticFiles:Headers:Access-Control-Allow-Methods"];
            }
        }); 

        /*
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
            {
                context.Context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
                context.Context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Content-Type";
                context.Context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH";
            }
        });
        */

        app.UseMvc();

}
```

I also tried creating the Web.config which is not created when you start a **framework Core** project and adding the config as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So I guess I'm doing something wrong outside of this part, anyone knows what can be wrong here?

Comment: Probably, helps this.
http://blog.thunderstrucksolutions.se/asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-cors-and-static-files/

Comment: I don't know why but i'm having `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` when trying to access your link, can you export it to pastebin.com please? I'm in a hurry here...

Comment: cached url: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kbbONQP0TMYJ:blog.thunderstrucksolutions.se/asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-cors-and-static-files/+&cd=3&hl=ja&ct=clnk&gl=jp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cors is more than just the headers, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) for more info in .NET.

In order to set CORS in .NET Core you need to add the Cors Services and configure them.

In the `ConfigureServices` add the following call:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

And in your `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Shows UseCors with CorsPolicyBuilder.
    app.UseCors(builder =>
       builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader());
}
```